# Why does process count in Performance Monitor disagree with that given by PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, process, performance-monitor

When setting up a trace in Windows Performance Monitor I have sometimes added "\Objects\Processes" to the list of Performance Counters

[image: see sample list].

Analyzing the results seems always to show a higher process count than what is given by PowerShell run at the same time, i.e. *PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-Process).Count* (The PowerShell result agrees with the total from WMIC, tasklist, etc.)

For example, a process count of 150 from PowerShell may correspond to a count of 165-170 in Performance Monitor. What would cause this discrepancy?

Comment: Perhaps, because they would include/exclude different system processes.  With so many processes running,  After an update, the count may be different again. I am curious why it matters.

Comment: The `sample interval` with performance monitor may be calculated values (sampled rate) and not realtime, but I'm not 100% certain but here's something more technical to read regarding the performance monitor counters in case it is applicable here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/perfctrs/about-performance-counters for these differences you notice. PowerShell, WMIC, and Taskkill may be realtime what is running right then and not calculated and such with sample sets.